# Having a problem converting code from Netlogo 5.1.0 to Netlogo 6.3.0

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to write an A* algorithm for my project however, I first made it in 5.1.0 and there it works. However I want it to work in 6.3.0

`set open sort-by [[f] of ?1 < [f] of ?2] open`

```
to-report find-a-path [ source-patch destination-patch]

  ; initialize all variables to default values
  let search-done? false
  let search-path []
  let current-patch 0
  set open []
  set closed []

  ; add source patch in the open list
  set open lput source-patch open

  ; loop until we reach the destination or the open list becomes empty
  while [ search-done? != true]
  [
    ifelse length open != 0
    [
      ; sort the patches in open list in increasing order of their f() values
;      set open sort-by [[f] of ?1 < [f] of ?2] open
      set open sort-by < [] open

      ; take the first patch in the open list
      ; as the current patch (which is currently being explored (n))
      ; and remove it from the open list
      set current-patch item 0 open
      set open remove-item 0 open

      ; add the current patch to the closed list
      set closed lput current-patch closed

      ; explore the Von Neumann (left, right, top and bottom) neighbors of the current patch
      ask current-patch
      [
        ; if any of the neighbors is the destination stop the search process
        ifelse any? neighbors4 with [ (pxcor = [ pxcor ] of destination-patch) and (pycor = [pycor] of destination-patch)]
        [
          set search-done? true
        ]
        [
          ; the neighbors should not be obstacles or already explored patches (part of the closed list)
          ask neighbors4 with [ pcolor != black and (not member? self closed) and (self != parent-patch) ]
          [
            ; the neighbors to be explored should also not be the source or
            ; destination patches or already a part of the open list (unexplored patches list)
            if not member? self open and self != source-patch and self != destination-patch
            [
              ;set pcolor 45

              ; add the eligible patch to the open list
              set open lput self open

              ; update the path finding variables of the eligible patch
              set parent-patch current-patch
              set g [g] of parent-patch  + 1
              set h distance destination-patch
              set f (g + h)
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

I tried reading the Netlogo dictionary but it couldnt help me.

Comment: I'd suggest consulting http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#tasks-replaced-by-anonymous-procedures

Comment: I have looked at the document above, however when tried to implement this in my code. It did not work and resulted in a different error which states that the variable f needs to be literal, which of course it is not.

Comment: Could you show us this newer version?

Comment: I used it like this:

      set open sort-by  [ [?1 ?2] -> [[f] of ?1 < [f] of ?2] ] open

Comment: That's one too many sets of square brackets. You don't need to encase the right side by a separate set.
`set open sort-by [ [?1 ?2] -> [f] of ?1 < [f] of ?2 ] open`